# How to add a progress ring to the splash screen in Windows 8?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, splash-screen

I need to activate the splash screen and add to it a progress ring in a Windows 8 metro app using C# and XAML.
I have added the extended splash screen but it is not showing at all! Can anybody tell me how to do this?

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using Windows.ApplicationModel;
    using Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;
    using Windows.Foundation;
    using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
    using SplashScreenSample; 

    // The Blank Application template is documented at     http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?        LinkId=234227

    namespace App1
    {
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides application-specific behavior to supplement the default Application class.
    /// </summary>
    sealed partial class App : Application
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes the singleton application object.  This is the first line of authored code
        /// executed, and as such is the logical equivalent of main() or WinMain().
        /// </summary>
        public App()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when the application is launched normally by the end user.  Other entry points
        /// will be used when the application is launched to open a specific file, to display
        /// search results, and so forth.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="args">Details about the launch request and process.</param>
        protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
        {
            // Do not repeat app initialization when already running, just ensure that
            // the window is active
           /* if (args.PreviousExecutionState != ApplicationExecutionState.Running)
            {
                bool loadState = (args.PreviousExecutionState ==                  ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated);
                ExtendedSplash extendedSplash = new ExtendedSplash(args.SplashScreen, loadState);
                Window.Current.Content = extendedSplash;
            }

            Window.Current.Activate();*/

            if (args.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Running)
            {
                Window.Current.Activate();
                return;
            }

            if (args.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
            {
                //TODO: Load state from previously suspended application
            }

            // Create a Frame to act navigation context and navigate to the first page
            var rootFrame = new Frame();
             rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));

             // Place the frame in the current window and ensure that it is active
            Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
             Window.Current.Activate();
            if (!rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage)))
            {
                throw new Exception("Failed to create initial page");
            }

            // Place the frame in the current Window and ensure that it is active
            Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
            Window.Current.Activate();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when application execution is being suspended.  Application state is saved
        /// without knowing whether the application will be terminated or resumed with the contents
        /// of memory still intact.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The source of the suspend request.</param>
        /// <param name="e">Details about the suspend request.</param>
        private void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
        {
            var deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();
            //TODO: Save application state and stop any background activity
            deferral.Complete();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when the application is activated to display search results.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="args">Details about the activation request.</param>
        protected override void OnSearchActivated(Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.SearchActivatedEventArgs args)
        {
            App1.SearchResultsPage1.Activate(args.QueryText, args.PreviousExecutionState);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! It's always better to provide a sample code for your question if possible to improve the post accuracy and get better results. Have a great day :)

Comment: You cannot do this with the built-in support for the splash screen.  Nor does that make sense, a store app *must* start in a reasonable time or it will be killed.  Too short to make a progress ring useful.  You'll need to create your own.  Not so sure if that will pass the store verification btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track by using the extended start screen.

You should start with the sample and quickstart, run that, see if it works for you
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh973049%28v=win.10%29.aspx
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Splash-screen-sample-89c1dc78

If the sample is working and your code is not, try to find what is different between the two, or alternatively migrate your code into the sample. It could be something is not proper on the XAML side too.

Answer (score 0):

This link is very helpful,and explain how you can add  a progress ring to the splash screen in Windows 8? 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868191.aspx#modify_the_launch_activation_handler