# How to add progress ring on splash screen

Tags: javascript, winjs

I am working on win 8 app using javascript. How to add progress ring on splash screen until app gets loaded and on hubpage till data loads?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13308516/how-to-add-a-progress-ring-to-the-splash-screen-in-windows-8

Comment: I am developing it in javascript. I didnt find anywhere a related post.

Comment: This really is a different question, with a different solution. Please reask -- i have an answer!

Comment: @DominicHopton Thanks for the reply. I am working on win 8 app using html5 javascript. I want to add the progress ring on splash screen until app loads and also on hubpage until data loads.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has posted a nice sample on MSDN with the nitty gritty details (see [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Splash-screen-sample-89c1dc78)), but here are the basics.

- In your application, include a new DIV that is an immediate child of `body`, and set it's style as:

Example:

```
.myExtendedSplash {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background-color: red; // your app colour
}
```

- Inside the application include your app's splash image, positioned appropriately (requires script, see the sample)
- Add a `<progress class="win-ring win-medium></progress>` to your splashscreen div you created in the first step

Boom!

The complexity comes from:

- needing to have the exact position of the OS splash, which is on the activated event args
- Needing adjust the position of this splash screen if the user changes the screen resolution or orientation while you are showing it (handle window resize, and the event args get updated)